# c++ for each vector of strings

Tags: c++, for-loop, std

```
    typedef std::vector<std::string> TVector;
    TVector a_list;

    populate vector...
    for_each(a_list.begin(),a_list.end(),std::toupper);
```

error

```
no matching function for call to 'for_each(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)
```

Do I need to iterate over the elements using the a standard for loop ? Or is there another way I am not allowed to use c++ 11 features.

Thanks

Comment: for (TVector::iterator i = a_list.begin(),a_list.end();++i) {

        std::transform(i->begin(), i->end(), i->begin(), ::toupper);

    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toupper` function is used for *characters*, not strings. It also *returns* the uppercase character, so won't work with `for_each`, but will with [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). There is also the problem that `std::toupper` exists in two overloads, and the compiler can't decide which one to use. Include `<cctype>` and use plain `toupper` (or optionally `::toupper`) to get the right function.

You need to iterate first over all strings in the vector, and the iterate again over the string to call `toupper`.

You can either do it manually, or use `transform` and use [functor objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B), something like

```
struct strtoupper
{
    std::string operator()(const std::string& str) const
    {
        std::string upper;
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(upper), ::toupper);
        return upper;
    }
};

// ...

std::transform(a_list.begin(), a_list.end(), a_list.begin(), strtoupper());
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a vector of `std::string` and `std::toupper` expects a `char` as parameter. So it can not be used. What you can do is:

`std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),[](std::string& s) { std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), std::toupper);});`

Answer (score 2):

`std::toupper` is an overloaded function; that’s why you’re getting `<unresolved overloaded function type>` in the error message. To select a particular overload, you need to cast it:

```
static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)
```

`for_each` is also not the right choice for this task—it will call `toupper` for each string in the list, then discard the result. [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) would be the appropriate choice—it writes its output to an output iterator. However, `toupper` works on characters, not strings. You could still use `transform` to call `toupper` for each character in a string:

```
std::transform(
    a_string.begin(),
    a_string.end(),
    a_string.begin(),
    static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)
);
```

It would probably be clearer in this simple case to use loops:

```
for (TVector::iterator i = a_list.begin(), end = a_list.end(); i != end; ++i) {
    for (std::string::size_type j = 0; j < i->size(); ++j) {
        (*i)[j] = toupper((*i)[j]);
    }
}
```

But if you wanted to write it with `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>` tools only, you could make a functor:

```
struct string_to_upper {
    std::string operator()(const std::string& input) const {
        std::string output;
        std::transform(
            input.begin(),
            input.end(),
            std::back_inserter(output),
            static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)
        );
        return output;
    }
};

// ...

std::transform(
    a_list.begin(),
    a_list.end(),
    a_list.begin(),
    string_to_upper()
);
```